# Graph Theory Cut Vertex

Tags: graph-theory

so I recently started learning about the graph theory and i came about this question:

> Show that a vertex c in the connected simple graph G is a cut vertex
>   if and only if there are vertices u and v, both different from c, such
>   that every path between u and v passes through c.

So from what i understand, a cut vertex is an vertex that if removed, would create 2 graphs from the original. Correct? So to prove the question above, would I simple do:

```
u---c---v
```

Is this correct? if not how would I show such case?

Comment: A cut vertex makes the graph disconnect after being removed.  Your drawing doesn't prove that.  You need to use words to explain why removing $c$ disconnects $G$.  Also, notice the "if and only if" statement ?  This means you need to do two proofs.  First, that if $c$ is a cut vertex, then there are vertices $u$ and $v$ as described.  And second, the other direction - if such $u$, $v$ exist, then $c$ is a cut vertex.

Comment: ok and how would i prove those two cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, we have to prove two implications. Suppose that $G$ is simple, undirected graph:

$\Rightarrow:$

Let's say we've got two vertices, $u ,v\neq c$
  such that every path between them passes through $c$
 . Let's remove $c$
  from $G$
  - we just cut every single way to get from $u$
  to $v$
  (and vice versa) so graph isn't connected anymore (look at definition of connectivity - graph is connected if and only if we can find path from any vertex to any other) - $c$
  was cut vertex.

$\Leftarrow$
 :

Let's say that $c$
  is cut vertex. Then, if we remove it from graph, it will constist of at least two connected components ($G$
  was connected before, so it was one connected component). Let's take $u$
  from one of them, and $v$
  from another - if now there's no way between them, when we had $c$
  in graph, all paths between them must have contained $c$
  - if there would be any that had not, it would still exist, and $u
 , v$
  would not be in other components.